# Is there any way to have a very lazy evaluation of Labels used in Salesforce Chatter messages?

Tags: chatter, customlabel, feeditem, language, lazy-loading

I'm currently working for a company whose main language is German though they are an increasingly multilingual company.

I have a requirement that when some event happens, notifications should be sent through Chatter to inform those interested in particular records that the event happened.

Currently I am simply inserting FeedItems which say what happened, like:

```
insert new FeedItem(
                Title = 'Opportunity',
                Body = message,
                ParentId = opportunity.OwnerId,
                LinkUrl = '/lightning/r/Opportunity/' + opportunity.Id + '/view'
        );
```

... but this results in the notification being in a single message regardless of who views the message.

Is there any way I can embed a reference to a label within FeedItem.Body which won't be evaluated until a user views the notification through the Salesforce UI?

If so, how?